# Array Merge and remove duplicate

Tags: php, arrays

I have two array from different queries:

```
Array
(
    [41] => 1
    [42] => 2
) 

Array
(
    [42] => 30215
    [43] => 15478
)
```

Now I want to have an array of all the items of the second array that are not duplicates of the first one.

```
Array
(
    [43] => 15478
)
```

`key => 42` is deleted out of the array, because it exists in the first array.

Comment: Do you actually want to merge them or just remove all items from array2 whose keys exist in array1?

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: @kingkero yes, you catch my need.

Comment: @Rizier123 , yes i tried $desired_array = $firstArray + $secondArray;
but result is not linking to me.

Comment: @ManishKumar ^ Add your attempt into your question.

Comment: It seems you have two accounts [manish-kumar](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4891333/manish-kumar) and [manish-prajapati](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1725386/manish-prajapati) and upvoting one answer from another account @Rizier123 have a look over these two they seems identical

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

Just use [`array_diff_key()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-key.php) to get the difference by the key, like this:

```
<?php

    $arr1 = [41 => 1, 42 => 2];
    $arr2 = [42 => 30215, 43 => 15478];

    print_r(array_diff_key($arr2, $arr1));

?>
```

output:

```
Array( [43] => 15478 )
```

Answer (score 1):

try to do with `$desired_array = $firstArray + $secondArray;`